# When i use my code in local vscode its giving only 63 as answer but when i use a different online complier it works fine

Tags: c, integer, long-integer, function-definition, luhn

This is a Luhn algorithm code and it works fine in an online complier but when I use it in my local vscode it is only giving 63 as output.

I dont know if its a memory issue as it late long variable.

i.e credit card number as input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Finds its Luhn algorithm to see if its a valid credit card number.
void checksum(long num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; num != 0; num /= 10, i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
        }
        else
        {
            int digit = 2 * (num % 10);
            sum = sum + (digit / 10) + (digit % 10);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
}
int main()
{
    long int num;
    // Takes credit Card number as input.
    do
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%li", &num);
    } while (num < 0);
    checksum(num);

    return 0;
}
```

My inputs are like `374245455400126`,`378282246310005`.
And output is always `63`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your input and expected output? Different results with different compilers normally points towards undefined behaviour in your application. Uninitialized variables, overflow, etc.

Comment: Your comment indicates that you are dealing with credit card numbers. These are not really numbers but more a sequence of digits. It is better to handle them as a string. Depending on your compiler it may easily happen that neither `int` nor `long int` can store values large enough for a credit card number.

Comment: @Karma0o7 Use long long int instead pf long int.

Comment: inputs are stored in "num" variable which is long type and "sum" is at max 2 digit number so its should be fine with storing in int data type.

Comment: Please do not change your code to show the solution. That makes all comments and answers useless. It also makes the whole post useless for any future visitors if the problem is no longer present in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result depends on the size of the type `long int` that can be equal either to the size of the type `int` or to the size of the type `long long int`.

So use the type `long long int` instead of the type `long int`.

Also as the program expects an unsigned value then instead of the signed type `long long int` it is even better to use the type `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: nope still the same thing i think i might have reinstall my vscode

Comment: @Karma0o7 Are you sure that you changed the type everywhere in the program?

Comment: @Karma0o7 you must keep in mind to update the format specifier for `scanf` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks i forgot to update my scanf modifier to "%lli" it worked.

Comment: Anyway, the Luhn algorithm should be used on a string rather than on an integer type. The code will be much simpler and you'll never run into any kind of integer overflow.

Comment: yeah but it was a question and i had to use long data type to do it thats why i couldn't use string